# Disable Bootstrap Font

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have a website that uses the bootstrap CSS/JS. I am suffering the problem when the bootstrap font conflicts with the font I would like to use. Example:

With my Font

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiGGn.png

But When I use the bootstrap CSS, the font conflicts with mine (Uses bootstrap Font instead of the one I have set)

Bootstrap CSS - There Font

https://i.stack.imgur.com/04gck.png

Is there anyway to Remove the bootstrap Font ( Typography ) or some how make my font be used instead?

On a side note: The bootstrap CSS/JS was added to website for less coding for me. The website it self was coded not using any class from Bootstrap.

Comment: I have even tried to remove the Typography from download bootstrap customize menu: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ Still no luck.

Comment: You will need to post some sample code, otherwise it is hard to see where is the issue exactly. Also, if you aren't using any of the Bootstrap's classes, check out [Normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) as it is only a reset stylesheet, and does not come with fully styled elements as Bootstrap.

Comment: Your stylesheet should come after the Bootstrap stylesheet, overriding the Bootstrap font declarations

Comment: Yes David you Are right! Problem solved!

Such a Foolish mistake. 


     <!--CSS Starts-->
  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/normalize.css">
    
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css"> 

I would like to thank everyone that answered or tried to help me. I should have paid more attention.

Comment: I notice you have bootstrap.css and bootstrap.min.css.  You only need the latter.  Otherwise you're loading the entire bootstrap css twice.  Also, are you using bootstrap 2 or 3?  Bootstrap 3 includes normalize in it so you wouldn't need it as well as the minified css.

Comment: Hello David. I am using both because I shall use a custom skin on top of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try making sure you're loading your custom CSS file after the bootstrap one in your page header. Eg:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />`

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/your-stylesheet.css" />`

Comment: I tried this on my site but it didn't work. I even moved all the font stylsheets along with the main stylesheet right before the </header> tag but it didn't work. Any other suggestions?